# knock on Scientific Linux 6.1? (perl script for knocking?)

Tags: security, perl, scientific-linux

I have an OpenWrt router where I installed knockd:

```
knockd.conf 
[options]
    logfile = /var/log/knockd.log

[openSSH]
    sequence    = 7000,8000,9000
    seq_timeout = 5
    command     = /usr/sbin/iptables -I INPUT -s %IP% -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
    tcpflags    = syn

[closeSSH]
    sequence    = 9000,8000,7000
    seq_timeout = 5
    command     = /usr/sbin/iptables -D INPUT -s %IP% -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
    tcpflags    = syn
```

and I'm having a notebook with Scientific Linux 6.1 from where I want to knock.. but seems there isn't any "knock" package for SL 6.1..

Where can I get the RPM for the knock binary? (Or are there any alternatives for knock? A perl script maybe?)

Comment: Security by obscurity :D

Comment: @JiriXichtkniha, well, it's extra-security measure, so why not. ;-)

Comment: So you trust more some perl script based portknocking than openssh which is developted by OpenBSD guys with security in mind? :D Is not great portknocking l33t tool running under root? LOL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with either bash's `/dev/tcp/host/port` or `netcat`.

Comment: IPA=192.168.1.1; nc -z -w 1 $IPA 7000; nc -z -w 1 $IPA 8000; nc -z -w 1 $IPA 9000